# Blender command Z is slow?

Tags: edit-mode, performance, osx

Alright I'm on mac latest OS, latest blender 2.79 and really just with command Z (this is just since updating) - it takes a WHILE like good 30s to undo something.

Modeling, everything else pretty fast but command Z is severely lagging. What is wrong here? Im on cycles if that matters

Comment: Does your scene contain a very large number of objects? I recently noticed that if a scene has a high amount of independent objects the undo command does take a considerably longer while, presumably has it iterates through all those objects.

Comment: It might just have to do with your process power of the mac, or if you have mass amount of objects that you have edited you'd probrably have to show "us" what your trying to undo first of all.

Comment: iirc undo loads a complete copy of the file from memory every time (except in edit mode), so with heavy files it can take a while. 30s is a bit extreme, but I could believe it on a very big scene. You could use the undo history (`Ctrl Alt Z`) to avoid needing repeated 30 second waits, or break your file up and work on bits separately (and use e.g. linking to put it all together).

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I have something like 100 objects. But some are stuck together - is there a way to (Ive tried group) aggregate objects so it takes up less space?

Comment: 100 objects is not a lot, I was thinking more in the several thousand order. You can join them wth `Ctrl+J`into one mesh but that will break instancing and perform worse while rendering. You can just place them in a separate file then link them as a group so they won't weight down your current working file.